# Problema al recuperar datos con petición GET

Tags: android, rest

Estoy haciendo una aplicación Android con Android Studio y necesito recuperar una serie de datos a través de una petición GET a la API de AccuWeather, pero no soy capaz, siempre me devuelve una cadena vacía. Realizo la consulta en la web de AccuWeather y me devuelve la siguiente cadena:

```
curl -X GET "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/307771?apikey={apikey}"
```

Yo utilizo la URL (http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/307771?apikey={apikey}) y el método "GET" en mi aplicación para recuperar los datos, pero no me devuelve nada. Alguien sabe a que se puede deber?

La aplicación funciona, porque si uso una URL que accede, por ejemplo, a la API de Google Books sí que recupera los datos.

El código de la clase que es este:

```
public class NetWorkUtils {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = NetWorkUtils.class.getSimpleName();
    static final String FUENTE_DATOS = "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/307771?apikey=dL0ChQdIyxsh7xC8Bd7J4BJLVlDLlOQX&language=es-es&details=true&metric=true";


    static String getDiasFestivos(String consulta){
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String respuesta = null;

        try{
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(FUENTE_DATOS).buildUpon().build();
            URL url = new URL(uri.toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append("\n");
            }

            if(builder.length() == 0){
                respuesta = "No se ha recuperado ningún dato";
                return respuesta;
            }
            respuesta = builder.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null){
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if(reader != null){
                try{
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, respuesta);
        return respuesta;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo la petición con una API KEY válida? Comparte el código que usas, no es necesario que pongas la API KEY completa. Google Books funciona si API KEY, pero no sé si AccuWeather tenga una versión que funcione sin API KEY.

Comment: La cadena que me ofrece AccuWeather con la API KEY es <curl -X GET "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/307771?apikey=dL0ChQdIyxsh7xC8Bd7J4BJLVlDLlOQX&language=es-es&details=true&metric=true">. Si pongo la url en un navegador devuelve los mismos datos que veo en la web de AccuWeather

Comment: Pero ahí te devuelve datos, ahora bien, tienes que estudiar y comprender ese JSON para saber cómo tienes que leerlo. ¿Por qué dices que devuelve una cadena vacía, cuando yo veo datos al abrir el enlace?

Comment: Ya. Primero quería verlos en la consola con Log.d, pero ya no devuelve nada. La url funciona en el navegador, pero en mi app no. Y por eso no entiendo porqué no funciona, porque con la de Google Books sí que funciona, y lo único que hago es cambiar la url en mi app

Comment: No es bueno que dejes tu API KEY aquí publicada. No sé si esa API KEY es de pago ¿? Otros podrían usarla para otros proyectos y te pasan factura a ti.  Si no ves nada en el Log es porque no estarás manejando bien la petición a la API o no estás manejando bien la respuesta. La API sí devuelve datos, ahora bien, como ya te dije, debes saber escribir bien la petición y manejar su respuesta. En cualquier caso, debes mostrar tu código si quieres que te ayudemos.

Comment: Por la API KEY no hay problema, solo creé la cuenta para hacer pruebas. En este código todavía no formateé la respuesta porque el Log.d me da una NullPointerException porque la cadena no se crea

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con: *« En este código todavía no formateé la respuesta porque el Log.d me da una NullPointerException porque la cadena no se crea»*. ? Debes plantear la pregunta según lo que ocurre en la realidad, no partiendo de suposiciones... Es decir, ¿el código funciona o no funciona? Si no funciona, ¿cuál es el error? y pon el mensaje de error. No podemos partir de suposiciones.

Comment: Tampoco entiendo tu forma de leer la respuesta. La API devuelve un JSON, ¿por qué usas un StringBuilder y demás historias para leer la respuesta?. Más bien deberías convertirlo a JSON y leer los datos. Las APIs existen para eso, no para leer las respuestas como si fueran archivos, línea por línea. Un JSON es una estructura de datos bien organizado, donde obtienes los datos por nombres de clave. Intentar leer la respuesta como un archivo, con saltos de línea y demás es un error.

Comment: Solo necesito recoger varios valores de los devueltos en la URL y presentarlos en varios TextView. Esta clase que muestro solo se ocupa de hacer la petición de los datos. Para presentar los datos por pantalla utilizo otra clase, antes me expliqué mal. En la clase que mostraría los datos tengo un botón, que al pulsarlo llama al método getDiasFestivos para realizar la consulta.  En este código que muestro si utilizo una URL de Google Books funciona, y en la ventana log de android studio puedo ver los valores devueltos

Comment: Pero si pongo la URL que aparece en el código que muestro me salta una NullPointerException. Estoy siguiendo los codelab propios de android, y ellos lo resuelven así.

Comment: ¿En qué parte exactamente te devuelve el NPE? ¿Qué codelabs estás siguiendo? Las respuestas JSON no se leen como veo que las estás leyendo tú, eso sería para leer un archivo cualquiera, pero no un JSON. ¿Podrías pasar el enlace del codelab que refieres?

Comment: El codelab es este https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-asynctask-asynctaskloader/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#0 en la Task 2. El NPE lo devuelve justo antes del último return, con la instrucción Log.d(LOG_TAB, respuesta)

Comment: Yo uso [`Volley`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) para este tipo de peticiones, es mucho más sencillo. De todos modos observa el comentario que hacen en el codelab, si agregas saltos de línea en la respuesta podrías tener errores cuando intentes leer tu JSON. En cuanto al NPE, esto `Log.d(LOG_TAG, respuesta);
    return respuesta;` debe ir dentro del `try`, no donde lo tienes ahora.

Comment: Ya probé a eliminar el salto de línea y nada, sigue sin funcionar. El problema tiene que ser al conectarse con la API, por hacerlo desde Android Studio por alguna configuración de seguridad o algo así, por que no le encuentro más explicación. ya que con la API de Google Books funciona sin problema. Gracias por tu ayuda de todas formas.

Comment: En caso de fallo debería escribir algún error en la pila: `
e.printStackTrace();` ¿Estás revisando eso?

Answer (score 0):

Tu ejemplo debe funcionar correctamente, comentas que no obtienes respuesta, primeramente asegura tener el permiso para internet definido en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

asegura que la llamada al método no interfiera con el Thread principal por lo tanto puedes usar un AsyncTask en el cual llamarías el mètodo `NetWorkUtils.getDiasFestivos("")` y en `onPostExecute()` obtendrías el resultado de la petición:

```
 class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                return NetWorkUtils.getDiasFestivos("");
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            System.out.print("RESULTADO: " +result);

        }
    }


    new MyAsyncTask().execute("");
```

Comment: Los pasos que me comentas ya los tenía implementados. De hecho si solo cambio la URL y me conecto a la API de Google Books, la app funciona sin problema. El problema viene al conectarme con la API de AccuWeather, por alguna configuración de seguridad o algo por el estilo me imagino.

Comment: agrega lo que muestra el LogCat, ya intentaste con el AsyncTask, en realidad tu url con la API Key funciona sin problema.